# How to write a route in Laravel without the root folder

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I want to write my routes that do not contain the root folder. This is my route currently where laravel is my root folder,

```
Route::get('laravel/cars', 'CarController@index');
```

and this is what i want,

```
Route::get('cars', 'CarController@index');
```

Below is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's `web.php` is very strong if you want to route like this then write it. It can be anything

```
Route::get('/cars', 'CarController@index');
```

OR

```
Route::get('/my/cars', 'CarController@index');
```

Both are work-able. Try them. You don't need to write `/laravel/`